# Breeze dataservice abstractrest - with sparse save response

Tags: rest, merge, breeze

I'm working with breeze labs AbstractRestDataServiceAdapter. In our data service adapter implementation's _createSaveRequest method our state.isModified branch emulates your oData adapters and only sends modified fields in the save request.

My issue is that our REST server returns a sparse response, i.e. input data and any fields on the entity that were updated. The result is that from a client perspective fields not returned in the saved entity are being wiped out.

I had seen merge logic in prior debugging sessions, so I initially thought I might be able to influence the save response processing via MergeStrategy, but it appears MergeStrategy doesn't apply in a save scenario. It appears AbstractRestDataServiceAdapter assumes the server is returning the full entity in a save response.

What options do we have for managing a sparse response from the server that preserves the state of fields not returned in the save response?

Is there a particular AbstractRestDataServiceAdapter method that we should override to manage merging the save response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `changeRequestSucceeded` method of the *breeze.labs.dataservice.abstractrest.js* adapter which processes each entity-specific response in particular the lines at the top:

```
var saved = saveContext.adapter._getResponseData(response);
if (saved && typeof saved === 'object') {
    // Have "saved entity" data; add its type (for JsonResultsAdapter) & KeyMapping
    saved.$entityType = saveContext.originalEntities[index].entityType;
    addKeyMapping();
} else {
    ...
}
saveContext.saveResult.entities.push(saved);
return saved;
```

Notice the references to `saveContext.originalEntities[index]`.

Suppose you know that the data in the `saved` object represent *just the specific properties* that you need to merge into the entity in cache.

Well you're in excellent position here, in YOUR version of this method in YOUR concrete implementation of this adapter, to combine the property values of `saved` and the property values of `saveContext.originalEntities[index]` before pushing that merged result into `saveContext.saveResult.entities`.

Comment: I was working with an earlier version that doesn't have the changeRequestSucceeded method and was playing with adding logic to our concrete class' _processSavedEntity method which seems like it would have worked, but grabbing the updated abstractrest code and overriding the method you suggest will put the code in a more logical location.<br/>I still wonder about the ability to influence the MergeStrategy used in entityManager.processSavedEnities() - although I haven't confirmed that is hit with your latest abstractrest code.

Comment: The MergeStrategy serves a different purpose and won't help you here. The MergeStrategy tells breeze whether it should update an entity that is already in a modified state. By default (PreserveChanges) it does not; it will when the value is OverWriteChanges. Neither matters to you. You want to blend incoming values with the values of the entity in cache, not decide whether or not to update the entity in cache.

Comment: Your description made sense to me so I marked it as the answer. I finally got around to implementation and it looks like the changeRequestSucceeded method is not set up in a manner that allows it to be overridden. It isn't represented in ctor.prototype and the invocation in tryRequestSucceeded directly calls the method rather than using the adapter.* approach used by other methods I can override...

Comment: Well I can fix THAT :-) The formerly private `changeRequestSucceeded` is now the "protected" `changeRequestSucceeded` (and supporting `_addKeyMapping`). Pushed to github (including bower package)

Comment: Outstanding! I always appreciate your very prompt responses @Ward.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement to actually return entities from the server on a save. Both the breeze.dataService.odata and the breeze.dataservice.mongo adapter have this issue where the server only returns some or parts of the saved entites.  The only requirement is that the dataService adapter saveChanges method return an object with two properties, i.e. something like

```
return { entities: entities, keyMappings: keyMappings };
```

If you actually have just the modified fields returned from the server then will have to manage the merge yourself, but this isn't really that complex. For each entity 'saved' simply locate it in the cache, set the changed properties and call acceptChanges and the return the 'located' entity in the result shown above.

Comment: After spending some time digging through the breeze code and debugging, again utilizing the breeze.labs.AbstractRestDataServiceAdapter, I found that MappingContext.mergeEntity() is being called and that the mergeStrategy is set to OverwriteChanges... that initially gave me some hope until I went up the call stack and found that the mapping context is created in entityManager.processSavedEntities() where the mergeStrategy is explicityly being set to OverwriteChanges (line 12927 of breeze.debug.js v1.4.11). While I should be able to do a manual merge myself, almost all the hooks are there...